# Sling Sightly: property of children with Javascript USE API?

Tags: sling, sightly, htl

**The Situation**

You are inside the JavaScript USE API for Sightly/HTL.

```
use([], function () {

  //your code here

  return {};
});
```

You then get a reference to a child resource like this:

```
var childRes = resource.getChild('my-child-node');
```

**The Question**

How do you get properties off of that resource?

hint: childRes.getValueMap() will give an exception.

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getValueMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `childRes.adaptTo(Packages.org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap)`?

Comment: Not excited about the fully qualified name in JS, but I suppose I'll have to get used to that if I'm going the JS Use Api route. Thanks.